# Creating nav bar title image for select view controllers produces weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I am created a logo in nav bar title spot on select view controllers using the below function:

```
class func setUpLogoOnNavBar(sourceVC: UIViewController) {

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

         let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 135, height: 90))
         imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
         let image = UIImage(named: "LogoAppHeaderBar.png")
         imageView.image = image

         sourceVC.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
      })
   }
```

By putting this on the main thread using GCD, it causes the image to jump to the left of nav bar when I am performing a standard push segue, it looks really bad. When I remove the GCD code from the below func, the logo jumping goes away. However, I get `This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.` Also the logo doesn't load in some view controllers because (I assume) it's not performing this operation on the main thread. How do I handle this so that this image loads on the main thread, but doesn't jump when I segue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using GCD at all when laying out your UI? It doesn't look like you are getting the image over the web, so laying out your nav bar should not be done asynchronously. Are you calling setUpLogoOnNavBar from another thread? You shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am calling `setUpLogoOnNavBar` in `viewDidLoad`. I tried doing it without the code for the main thread and I got the warning from the compiler I mentioned above. The image also doesn't load on some view controllers without GCD.

Comment: When you call this in viewDidLoad, your view is already laid out. Set the logo in an initializer, or possibly in view will appear